# Angular 2: Change element based on authenticated property

Tags: angular, authentication

I've got an Angular 2 app that I have integrated authentication into using a **service**.  The user can login, and when there is a token in the **localStorage** the user is considered authenticated.  I have a button in the navbar for Login that brings up a modal login form.  After the user is authenticated using the form, it is closed, but the button doesn't change to the Logout button.  I have set it up to use a property on `app.component` called `IsAuthenticated`, which gets it's value from the authentication service `isAuthenticated()` method, which returns an Observable of type boolean indicating whether or not the user has been authenticated.  But this property doesn't change when the user has been authenticated, even though the state has changed. I've tried a lot of things to get this to respond to the **state change**, but nothing has worked.  Any help is appreciated!

`authentication.service.ts` (just isAuthenticated function):

```
public isAuthenticated(): Observable<boolean> {
  let token = localStorage.getItem('currentUser');
  if (token) {
    let tokenObject = JSON.parse(token);
    let expiresOn = moment(tokenObject.expires);
    // Confirm there is a token, and it's expiration is later than now
    let isLoggedIn = tokenObject.token !== '' && expiresOn > moment();
    return Observable.of(isLoggedIn);
  }
  return Observable.of(false);
}
```

`app.component.ts`:

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public IsAuthenticated: boolean;
  loginModal: LoginComponent;

  constructor (
    private modalService: NgbModal,
    private authService: AuthenticationService
  ) { }

  openLogin(): void {
    this.modalService.open(LoginComponent, { size: 'sm' });
  }

  logout(): void {
    if (confirm('Are you sure you want to log out?')) {
      this.authService.logout();
      this.IsAuthenticated = false;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.authService.isAuthenticated()
      .subscribe(loggedIn => this.IsAuthenticated = loggedIn);
  }
}
```

`app.component.html`:

```
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">
    <li class="nav-item">
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="openLogin()" *ngIf="!IsAuthenticated">Login</button>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="logout()" *ngIf="IsAuthenticated">Logout</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

When the user clicks the "**Login**" button, the modal pops up, and I can login, but when it's done the Login button is still displayed, not the Logout, and I have other UI elements using the same `ngIf` that don't change either...  What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Edited**

Change `*ngIf="isAuthenticated"` to `*ngIf="authService.isAuthenticated()"`, IsAuthenticated is a function so you must call it as such by adding the parenthesis and it is a function of your service so you must call the instance of the service as well.

Comment: I understand it's a little confusing because I have named both the property on the app.component, and the function in the authentication.service "IsAuthenticated", but actually the function is in the service, and starts with a lowercase i, the one in the component is a property, not a function, and it begins with an uppercase I.  Regardless, I have tried that and it returned an error saying that IsAuthenticated is not a function...

Comment: edited again sorry for all the edits lol that should work now though

Comment: Yep, that worked once I changed the function in the service to just return a boolean, and not an observable.  Thanks!